# Getting a collection of successors in Java

Tags: java, collections, backtracking

In this method, I'm trying to get the collection of successors from the current one. This is for the Tents and Trees game in Java where I extract the pattern from a file to build the board. '%' represents a tree, '.' represents an empty spot, '^' represents a tent, '#' represents the grass.

```
public Collection<Configuration> getSuccessors() {

        Collection<Configuration> successors = new LinkedList<Configuration>();
        return successors;

        //return new ArrayList<>();  // replace
    }
```

I don't know if this is the right way, but it doesn't return anything when I run the program. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you don't really understand what the code is doing. I suggest you follow [a good tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) for the Java collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating an empty LinkedList and returning it. This LinkedList has 0 elements, so you return anything.

You need to insert something in the LinkedList.

I hope my answer will be helpful.